# Cannot use id on column title when pivoting and colum values are mixed

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, sql, sql-server

In this query:

```
select *
from
(
  select distinct a.id as 'Id Documento', 
    b.valor, 'index'+cast(row_number() over(partition by a.id order by b.idIndice) as varchar(10)) rn
  from tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_Documentos as a
  join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_Indexacao as b on a.id = b.idDocumento
  join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_DocType as c on a.idDocType = c.id
  join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_DocType_Index as d on c.id = d.docTypeId
  where d.docTypeId = 40 
  and  (b.idIndice = 11 AND b.valor = '11111111' OR b.idIndice = 12 AND b.valor = '11111')
) src
pivot
(
  max(valor)
  for rn in (Index1, Index2)
) piv
```

- How to add the value of b.idIndice in the 2 pivoted columns?

I have this:

```
 id Documento  Index1 Index2
```

I need

```
  id Documento 11 12
```

Second. I am getting

```
Id Documento    Index1     Index2
13          11111111   11111111
14          11111111   11111111
16          11111      11111
```

It is mixing the values... the value '11111111' should be on Index1 column and '11111' should be on Index2 columns.

What can I do?